# set focus on textbox popup asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, focus

How can i set focus on the first textbox control in a popup (modal)? It's a login window.
I tried javascript, but that failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `AjaxControlToolkit.Utility.SetFocusOnLoad(YouTextBoxID);`

Comment: Try in modalpopup extender's load event

Comment: Modal pop up itself has a load event.                       protected void YourModalPopUpID_ModalPopupExtender_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AjaxControlToolkit.Utility.SetFocusOnLoad(YouTextBoxID);
    }

Comment: The event gets fired, but the textbox control is not getting the focus. this is the modelpopup code: <act:ModalPopupExtender ID="popup" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnLogIn" PopupControlID="pnlLoginOverlay" BehaviorID="MPE" CancelControlID="btnCancel" />

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample

In MARKUP:

```
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" BehaviorID="UserSearchModalBehavior" ID="mpeSearch" PopupControlID="pUserSearch" TargetControlID="btnFindUser"
    OkControlID="btnUserSearchClose" CancelControlID="ibClose" />
```

In JavaScript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad() {
        var modalPopup = $find("UserSearchModalBehavior");
        if (modalPopup != null) {
            modalPopup.add_shown(OnPopupShow);                
        }
    }

    function OnPopupShow() {
        var tb = $get("tbSearchQuery");
        tb.focus();
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the `body onload` you can add some `javascript`. and set focus to textbox you want

E.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function setFocus() {
                document.getElementById('TextBox2').focus();
            }
        </script>


<body  onload="setFocus();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick='ani1();' />
    </form>
</body>
```

The `TextBox2` get focused once page is loaded

Comment: where exactly would i be putting this code? the page in which the user is atm or the usercontrol?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `focus()` in the `onload` event in your ASP.NET page which declares your TextBox:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('<%= yourTextBoxID.ClientID %>').focus();"></body>
```

You can use the `<body>` tag with content placeholders or forms.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to call the popup from js, use this:

```
function openPopup() {
    $find('BehaviorID_of_your_popup').show();
    document.getElementById('<%= theTextBox.ClientID %>').focus();
}
```

if you want to call it form server side, this should work:

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    popup.Show();
    theTextBox.Focus();
}
```